# How to set photo at background

Tags: css, html

Recently, I often see sites where the background image is photo. How to do the same and that the picture was stretched to contract under different resolutions?

Comment: Never heard of "view page source" I presume?

Comment: Right now I dont remember any site with need background

Comment: what you want to say `background image is photo`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Often, when the site had not yet opened hang beautiful photos on the whole background and the registration form for such notification, never seen anything like it?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava yeah )) but without sliding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    html or body { 
                background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
            }
```

For more tutorial Best resource [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: @ShailenderArora thanx and there is lot of method in given link as per question.

Comment: i know but i like this method :-)

Comment: Good answer, Arpit! But comments are not for discussion please delete your comments and also @ShailenderArora. And I shall delete mine)

Answer (score 2):

i hope you are looking like this :- http://jsfiddle.net/GNxqK/embedded/result/

we can achieve this target through :-

```
background-size: cover;
```

and the image will adjust according to body of the page.... as per the demo....